Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Autoinstall Wi-Fi Connectivity
Hello and thanks in advance.
I'm trying to autoinstall Ubuntu 22.04 LTS from USB.
I have successfully edited grub.cfg and created both "meta-data" and "user-data" files.
Autoinstall launches correctly but does not connect to the Wi-Fi network I have configured in my "user-data" file. If I add a "interactive-sections: - network" block to "user-data" I can see that the issue appears to be the lack of wireless drivers as the only NIC displayed is eth0. At this same screen I see "Wifi support packages will be installed in the target system".
Autoinstall works perfectly from a hardwired connection and I know the drivers are available because when I perform a normal (interactive/manual) install from the same source .iso I can connect to Wi-Fi successfully. It seems as though I need to "load" the drivers into the autoinstall environment? This is where I am at a total loss.
I have read and read but still no success. How can I create the required netplan file for autoinstall to apply and use? (/etc/netplan/00-installer-config-wifi.yaml) and how should I "add" it to my user-data file?
Any help would be greatly apprceiated!
